# Animated gif is not animating on SplashScreen

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, splash-screen

I want to show Splash Screen while login to the system. Everything works fine but GIF is not animating on Splash Screen. Maybe form becomes deactivated position or something else. I do not know why. I put the animated gif in the PictureBox and I have tested the gif. I am working on Windows Forms on VS2012.

```
frmSplash = new FrmSplashScreen();
frmSplash.Show();
.
.
.
//STUFF to do
.
.
frmSplash.Close();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried displaying it in a `WebBrowser` control in the splash screen?

Comment: My answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770415/windows-form-application-splash-screen-label-not-updating/45635821#45635821) can be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing work on the UI thread, the splash screen can't be updated, since it is running on the same thread, so the GIF is not animated. If possible, do the initialization on another thread.