# Windows Form Application - Splash screen label not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I have a windows form application which is supposed to show a splash screen with a label field that I want to update as the main form (called welcome.cs) loads in the background. The splash screen shows & hides just fine, but the label doesn't update.

I've done a lot of research but haven't quite found the solution.

Program.cs

```
/// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using (new SingleGlobalInstance(1000))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            SplashScreen splashscreen = new SplashScreen();
            splashscreen.ShowSplashScreen();

            Welcome welcome = new Welcome(splashscreen); //Takes some time to load
            splashscreen.CloseForm();
            Application.Run(welcome);

        }
    }
```

Splashscreen.cs

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        //Delegate for cross thread call to close
        private delegate void CloseDelegate();
        private delegate void UpdateStatusDelegate(string status);
        private static SplashScreen splashScreen;
        private Thread thread = null;

        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ShowSplashScreen()
        {
            // Make sure it is only launched once.

            if (splashScreen != null)
                return;
            thread = new Thread(ShowForm);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        static private void ShowForm()
        {
            splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
            Application.Run(splashScreen);
        }

        public void CloseForm()
        {
            splashScreen.Invoke(new CloseDelegate(CloseFormInternal));
        }

        static private void CloseFormInternal()
        {
            splashScreen.Close();
        }

        public void UpdateStatus(string status)
        {
            splashScreen.Invoke(new UpdateStatusDelegate(UpdateStatusInternal), status);
        }

         private void UpdateStatusInternal (string status)
        {
             if (splashScreen != null && splashScreen.IsHandleCreated)
             {
                 lblStatus.Text = status;
             }

        }
    }
```

Welcome.cs

```
public Welcome(Splashscreen splashscreen)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        //Code to log the user into the system

        splashScreen.UpdateStatus("Logging in...");
        //my expectation is that UpdateStatus call will update the label displayed on the splash screen but it doesn't.

        //Do more stuff.....
}
```

Does it have something to do with multi-threading or is it because im creating a new instance of splashscreen in welcome.cs before calling UpdateStatus? How would I get around this?

Comment: You are creating a **new** `SplashScreen` in the `Welcome` form, not referencing the one you are already displaying. You need to pass a reference of the existing splash screen to the constructor of the `Welcome` form in order to use that existing reference.

Comment: I missed that you trying to have multiple UI threads? Thats very wrong, remove the part that creates its own thread to run on. You are also calling `Application.Run` more than once, which is not recommended.

Comment: The reason though that it didn't work is that the reference you create in the main routine is also not the instance that is displayed, you create a new, private instance of the splash screen as some kind of incorrect attempt at the singleton pattern. The way you have it coded, you can't get the actual reference to the displayed form.

Comment: After reading your comment about not being able to get the actual reference, I converted ShowSplashScreen, CloseForm, UpdateStatus to static methods. Now there is only one instance of SplashScreen which is created within the ShowForm. I then added a timer to the SplashScreen form which updates the lblStatus. It works!! However, I'll put it down as a temporary solution and will definitely do some more research on this topic to improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
 static void Main()
 {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

     string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

     // Creates the Splash
     splash = new FrmSplash();

     //Opens the Splash in a new Thread, this way any gifs, progress bars, lablels changes will work because the main thread isnt blocked
     var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         splash.ShowDialog();
     });

      while (!splash.Created) // wait the splash screen form load process
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);

     UpdateSplashMessage("Loading the program... Please wait");         
     // Some slow initialization code.
     // ...

     //Close splash screen
     CloseSplash();

     Application.Run(args);
 }

 static void CloseSplash()
 {
     splash.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
     {
         splash.Close(); // Closes the splash that is running in the other thread
     }));
 }

 static void UpdateSplashMessage(string msg)
 {
     splash.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
     {
         splash.AtualizarMensagem(msg);
     }));
 }
```

Note that you will need to create a method called AtualizarMensagem(string str) in your splash screen form, like this

```
public void AtualizarMensagem(string novaMsg)
{
    lblCarregando.Text = novaMsg;
}
```

I have this code in my "useful snnipets" folder, it always works for me.
Hope this helps.